# Mockito Mock service class

Tags: java, mockito

I want to `InjectMocks` into my interface and not my service class , so far its not possible with Mockito (I am using Mockito 2.8.9). I have used SpringBoot and using `@MockBean` I am able to test interfaces of services but with `@Mock` of SpringMvc I can only test a concrete class, why and what can I do to test services?

Any suggestion on how to get this to interface level.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EmployeeServiceImpl.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTest {
    @org.mockito.Mock
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao; 

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService ;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void SaveEmployee() throws Exception {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmployeeName("valentine");
        employee.setSalary(400);
        employee.setDepartmentId(1);
        employee.setEmployeeId(1);

         Employee employee1 ;
         when(employeeDao.addEmployee(employee)).thenReturn(employee);

        employee1  = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);

        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(employee);
        assertEquals(employee1.getSalary(), employee.getSalary());

       Mockito.verify(employeeDao).addEmployee(employee);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you test a concrete class (implementation), you need to use InjectMocks for that class and not its interface

Comment: but in springboot when i use @mockBean i am able to test services

Answer (score 3):

So i solved this by first creating Bean in Config class that returns interface of Dao

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EmployeeDao employeeDao(){
        return Mockito.mock(EmployeeDao.class);
    }
}
```

Then i used the profile in my test and set configContxt TO my Config Class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes ={ EmployeeServiceImpl.class, Config.class})
public class EmployeeServiceTest1 {


    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
```